# Unable to change dropdown element color in react-js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new in react-js.I was making a dropdown in my nav bar using the react-bootstrap but am unable to change the color of the text and the dropdown button using css.It is always having the default color of blue.I changed other properties of it and they all were changing very fine using css but only the color value is not having any effect.It would be helpful if someone can help me.

```
<NavDropdown title="Random" style = {{color : 'white' }}  >
                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Deals</NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Amazon Skills</NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Amazon Devices</NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Apps and Games</NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
```

Comment: have you checked `className` instead of `style`?

Comment: you have to style the anchor inside the dropdown

Answer (score 1):

This is because the NavDropdown component does not have this style in its container. It's an `a` element inside the dropdown `div`.

One way to change this is to have your custom `styles.css` file imported after the default bootstrap css and override this specific property, like this:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./styles.css";
```

And inside the styles.css file, insert:

```
div.dropdown.nav-item > a {
 color: red;
}
```

There are many other ways to do that, please refer to the [Theming](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/getting-started/theming/) section of the React-Bootstrap documentation for more elegant solutions.

Comment: I am not talking about items but the one which is displayed in front.

Comment: I know that, this selector is for the active item.

Comment: But I don't have any div?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give me a solution which do not need external css file.